# Ruby Zlib: What is the purpose of orig_name=?

Tags: zlib

My code is like this:

```
gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.open('test.zip')
gz.orig_name = "test.csv"
gz.write("testing writing to zipped file")
gz.close
```

What I am trying to do:

```
When using zip extractor application, test.zip will be unzipped to test.csv
```

I used orig_name method thinking that when I will try to extract the zip with other zip extractor like archive utility, the resulting file would be 'test.csv'. But the file is still 'test'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "other zip extractor" you mean the gzip utility, you'd need to use the `-N` option of gzip to use the name stored in the gzip header.  Otherwise it will just use the compressed file name with the `.gz` removed.

Comment: I am using https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rar-extractor-free/id646295438 on Mac.

Comment: There is probably not a way to get that utility to use the name in the gzip header.  Instead use tar.gz.